# Mysql Updating with if condition within a Table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update

I am unable to update 2 fields in a Table using UDPATE AND IF condition. Need help.

I have an invoice table where in If field Nos=0 I need to update field Qty from Capacity and field Nos=1 in the same table.

My sql statement is not working:

```
UPDATE INVDTLS_draft1 SET `Nos`=1, `Qty`=`Capacity` IF (Nos=0) WHERE id=id
```

error message:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF (Nos=0) WHERE id=id' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query, using `AND` operator

```
UPDATE INVDTLS_draft1 SET `Nos`=1, `Qty`=`Capacity` WHERE id=id AND Nos=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE INVDTLS_draft1 SET 
Nos=1,
Qty = if(nos=0, capacity, Qty)
WHERE id=?
```

This "does nothing" to qty if nos != 0.

Comment: This statement is updating all the records in the table, it is not checking for condition

Comment: @user1114409 I just copied the where clause from the question. I assumed everyone knew OP meant an app code variable named "id". I've edited the answer to show a placeholder instead

Answer (score 0):

Why id=id? I think you need this:

```
UPDATE INVDTLS_draft1
SET    `Nos`=1, `Qty`=`Capacity`
WHERE  Nos=0
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a simple statement, not sure why I was thinking about IF condidtion to do this. Thankyou very much.